# Alterando save do ngResource e usando o CORS (Cross Domain)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, resources, cors

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com angular, e estou tendo um problema com o módulo ngResource.

Preciso chamar uma URL de outro sistema, para isso eu já adicionei os headers necessários na outra aplicação. Porem no meu request eu preciso chamar usando um **Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded**, para isso eu alterei o método save do $resource. Mais quando eu faço a alteração ele para de fazer as requisições em CORS e apresenta o erro abaixo.

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost' is therefore not allowed access.

Esse erro só é apresentado quando eu altero os headers do método save segue abaixo a maneira que estou alterando.

```
$resource(config.url.generalSystems + '/index.php',{},{save:{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}, method: 'POST'}}).save("Action=Login&validator=&RequestedURL=&Lang=pt_BR&TimeOffset=&User="+Login+"&Password="+Senha, function (retorno) {
     console.log(retorno);
}
```

Abaixo segue o código que funciona usando  o CORS, porém ele não envia o **Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded** ele envia o **Content-type: application/json**, e não pode pois não é compativel com a outra aplicação.

```
$resource(config.url.generalSystems + '/index.php').save({Action : 'Login', validator : '', RequestedURL : '', Lang : 'pt_BR', TimeOffset : '', User : Login, Password : Senha}, function (retorno) {
    console.log(retorno);
}
```

Oque eu preciso fazer para que o CORS funcione no primeiro exemplo?

> Obs: Já foi adicionado o Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * / * e o Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept

Comment: Uma pergunta parecida aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27668794/1310945 - da uma olhada pra ver se te ajuda.